# Maven build error - Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.5.5

Tags: java, maven, build

I am trying to build project using Maven. Unfortunately I have no experience with maven so I am a bit helpless. It is most likely caused by the riak submodule. Here is the github repo with code: [YCSB](https://github.com/LordFazole/YCSB/tree/riak_binding)

My system:

```
Apache Maven 3.2.2 (NON-CANONICAL_2015-04-01T06:56:20_mockbuild; 2015-04-01T08:56:20+02:00)
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_51, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.51-4.b16.fc21.x86_64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.1.5-100.fc21.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Maven stack trace:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.5.5:single (default) on project ycsb: Failed to create assembly: Artifact: com.yahoo.ycsb:riak-binding:jar:0.3.1-RC1-SNAPSHOT (included by module) does not have an artifact with a file. Please ensure the package phase is run before the assembly is generated. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.5.5:single (default) on project ycsb: Failed to create assembly: Artifact: com.yahoo.ycsb:riak-binding:jar:0.3.1-RC1-SNAPSHOT (included by module) does not have an artifact with a file. Please ensure the package phase is run before the assembly is generated.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to create assembly: Artifact: com.yahoo.ycsb:riak-binding:jar:0.3.1-RC1-SNAPSHOT (included by module) does not have an artifact with a file. Please ensure the package phase is run before the assembly is generated.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.mojos.AbstractAssemblyMojo.execute(AbstractAssemblyMojo.java:541)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.archive.ArchiveCreationException: Artifact: com.yahoo.ycsb:riak-binding:jar:0.3.1-RC1-SNAPSHOT (included by module) does not have an artifact with a file. Please ensure the package phase is run before the assembly is generated.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.archive.phase.ModuleSetAssemblyPhase.addModuleArtifact(ModuleSetAssemblyPhase.java:337)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.archive.phase.ModuleSetAssemblyPhase.addModuleBinaries(ModuleSetAssemblyPhase.java:231)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.archive.phase.ModuleSetAssemblyPhase$1.accept(ModuleSetAssemblyPhase.java:140)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.model.Assemblies.forEachModuleSet(Assemblies.java:40)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.archive.phase.ModuleSetAssemblyPhase.execute(ModuleSetAssemblyPhase.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.archive.DefaultAssemblyArchiver.createArchive(DefaultAssemblyArchiver.java:178)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.mojos.AbstractAssemblyMojo.execute(AbstractAssemblyMojo.java:484)
    ... 21 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :ycsb
```

I have no idea what it means so I guess you are my only hope :D

EDIT:
After adding plugin suggested by Subodh Joshi:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.5.5:single (default) on project binding-parent: Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive jar-with-dependencies: You must set at least one file.
```

EDIT2:
`mvn compile` works fine, but `mvn package` fails with above error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to add `maven-assembly-plugin` in your `pom.xml` file

```
 <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <mainClass>com.test.MainClassName</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>make-assembly</id> 
          <phase>package</phase> <!-- packaging phase -->
          <goals>
            <goal>single</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Which one? The one in the root of the project or the one in the riak module?

Comment: Did you run `mvn` command after adding this in `pom.xml` file

Comment: I don't know what you mean.

Comment: I did run `mvn package`.

Comment: After adding this in your pom file did you run `mvn clean install` or any other command

Comment: In Parent project or any module?

Comment: Please check if `maven-assembly-plugin` jar is there in `.m2` directory

Comment: There are two: 2.5.5 and 2.2-beta-5

Comment: Which one used by your project classpath also check .m2 contain jar or not?

Comment: Both of them contains jar. It seems both plugins are used (??)

Comment: No you have to check your project classpath it will tell you which jar it is using

Comment: It's not in the classpath

Comment: If its not classpath it should throw exception.All the jar needed by project should be in classpath

Comment: The project classpath in maven is really confusing :( It is maven-assembly-plugin:2.5.5

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87780/discussion-between-subodh-joshi-and-thekrow).

Answer (score 2):

When I trying to work with Netbeans 12.0 OpenJDK 15, I needed import some library projects (.jar) that I developed using OracleJDK 8u231 for some code testings; the result was similiar to the question:

```
 Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.6:single (make-assembly) 
on project rgbfw-as-core-db: Execution make-assembly of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.6:single 
failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing 
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.6:single: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
```

For me, the solution was update the version of the "maven-compiler-plugin" and "maven-assembly-plugin" on my library projects(.jar) before make new run of "Clean and build" of the Netbeans Project explorer.
Current versions:

maven-compiler-plugin(3.8.1)

maven-assembly-plugin(3.3.0)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the dependecy for it in the pom.xml?

note the error its from maven-assembly-plugin:2.5.5

go to https://mvnrepository.com/ and search for "maven-assembly-plugin"

pick the right version 2.5.5 (or better ) and copy it to your
 list in your pom file

If you have a similar plugin under your  in your pom file...well

delete it and  voila

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://mvnrepository.com/ and search for "maven-assembly-plugin"
pick the right version 2.5.5 (or better ) and copy it to your
<dependencies> list in your pom file
Delete the plugin under your <plugins> in your pom file if its the same version as the dependency

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Maven software should be updated one and update the environment variable and path.

Even not working, remove the environment variable and path.

Eclipse Preferences>Maven>Installations>Add Maven Installed home path and name