# YCSB (0.6.0) Riak Binding (2.1.1) constantly throw maven-assembly-plugin error when package

Tags: maven, riak, ycsb

I am new to YCSB and Riak. When I follow this guide https://github.com/cvitter/YCSB-Riak-Binding
 to benchmark test on Riak with `mvn clean package`, it throws:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.5.5:single (default) on project binding-parent: Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive jar-with-dependencies: You must set at least one file.
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: It seems that somebody once has the same problem but couldn't resolve it yet: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32172065/maven-build-error-failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-assemb/32172090#32172090 @LordBean

Comment: Hi Sombre, the repo you are trying to use is not the latest. All of the code changes I made to that repo were moved to the official Basho repo which can be found at https://github.com/basho-labs/YCSB/tree/master/riak . Please try that repo and let us know if you have any additional issues.

Comment: Actually I found the solution by cut & paste <module>distribution</module> to the last line of <module> section of pom.xml. 
(even in the newest version).

Comment: Dear Craig, by the way, I want to find a way to use custom dataset instead of YCSB's auto generated data. For example: to use public dataset of Facebook or Twitter as the input for insert() function of YCSB Client. Is that possible?

Comment: Sombre, I am sure it is but it would require you to create your own fork of the YCSB code and alter the write portions of the code to insert the data you want to use for testing. The YCSB code is pretty straightforward so it shouldn't be very hard.

Comment: Thanks for your encouragement. I managed to do it!